# Inserting data into a foreach array before moving to another Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, foreach, google-sheets

I have built a Google Sheet to dispatch delivery trucks for our company. We have a sheet called "Unscheduled Jobs" which lists all the jobs waiting to be done. When planning a route for the day these are moved to sheets named after each driver. As the driver does his deliveries he will mark each job completed. Every 5 minutes a script will run that will move the jobs marked completed to a sheet called "Completed Jobs" and insert the driver name (Column O) as well as a date and time stamp (Column N) when the job was completed.

The script we are currently is rather slow so I am trying to do this using an array but not having any success. I am very much a novice at this so I would appreciate if anyone kind enough to respond could explain what their code is doing.

The code I am trying to use:

```
function reschedule() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Driver'));
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Driver');var clearrange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
    var val = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
        .getValues();


   var arr = [],
        rowsToWriteBack = [];
        rowsToWriteBack.push();


    val.forEach(function (r, i) {
        r[3] == 'Completed' ? arr.push(r) + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "MM-dd-yyyy EEE hh:mm a") : rowsToWriteBack.push(r)
    });


    if (arr.length > 0) { 
        targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)
        .setValues(arr);

      clearrange.clear({contentsOnly:true});
      sheet.getRange(3, 1, rowsToWriteBack.length, rowsToWriteBack[0].length)
      .setValues(rowsToWriteBack);
    }

}
```

Comment: arr.push(r) will return the index of r in arr. so arr.push(r) + somedate is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonas w's comment seems right on.
Are you trying to add a time-stamp column to your row if the job is completed?
If so, perhaps change these lines:

```
val.forEach(function (r, i) {
    r[3] == 'Completed' ? arr.push(r) + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "MM-dd-yyyy EEE hh:mm a") : rowsToWriteBack.push(r)
});
```

to something like this:

```
val.forEach(function (r, i) {
    if r[3] === 'Completed' {
      r[4] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "MM-dd-yyyy EEE hh:mm a");
      arr.push(r)
    } else {
      rowsToWriteBack.push(r)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That works excellent. The final code, in case anyone is interested, looks like this....

```
function rescheduleDriversJobs() {

//Get an exlusive lock on the sheet

var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
try {
   lock.waitLock(2000);
 } catch (e) {

 //Displayes a browser message if unable to get an exclusive lock on the sheet
   Browser.msgBox('Another script is running. Please try again later');

//Releases the lock if unable to get an exclusive lock on the sheet
   lock.releaseLock();

//Cancels the Script   
   return;
 }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name'));
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  var clearrange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Completed Jobs');
    var val = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
        .getValues();

//Builds the arrays    
   var arr = [],
        rowsToWriteBack = [];
        rowsToWriteBack.push();

//populates the arrays    

    val.forEach(function (r, i) {
    if (r[3] === 'Completed') {

    //Adds Date and Time stamp to Column N of the "Completed Jobs" sheet
      r[13] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "MM-dd-yyyy EEE hh:mm a");

//Adds the name of the driver completing the job to Column O of the "Completed Jobs" sheet
      r[14]="Driver Name";
      arr.push(r)
    } else {
      rowsToWriteBack.push(r)
   }
});


   if (arr.length > 0) {

    //Inserts empty rows after the header row of the "Completed Jobs" sheet to populate with array data
    targetSheet.insertRowsBefore(2, arr.length)

    //Selects the range on the target sheet to be populated with data from the array (The empty rows we just created with the above line)
    targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)

    //Send the data to the target sheet
    .setValues(arr);

//Clears that data that has been moved
     clearrange.clear({contentsOnly:true});
      sheet.getRange(3, 1, rowsToWriteBack.length, rowsToWriteBack[0].length)
      .setValues(rowsToWriteBack);
    }

//Releases the lock so other scripts can run    
lock.releaseLock();

}
```